# Makefile: Use target filepath in prereq

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following project structure:

```
+-Makefile
+-src/
  +-a/
  | +-foo.py
  +-b/
  | +-foo.py
  +-c/
  | +-foo.py
```

Each `foo.py` file is a different file with exactly the same name (ie they have different inodes but are all literally called 'foo.py' - although of course in reality the name is not foo.py, which is just an example).

**I wish to create a GNU Makefile rule which, when run, creates the following structure:**

```
+-Makefile
+-src/
  +-a/
  | +-foo.py
  | +-a.zip
  +-b/
  | +-foo.py
  | +-b.zip
  +-c/
  | +-foo.py
  | +-c.zip
```

This is the closest I have been able to figure out, although of course it fails due to using a target variable in the prereqs which doesn't seem to be allowed:

```
SRCDIR = src/
PRJ_DIRS = a b c
SRC_FILE = foo.py

# This next rather nasty line turns PRJ_DIRS in to, e.g., src/a/a.zip etc.
ZIP_FILES = $(addprefix $(SRCDIR),$(join $(PRJ_DIRS),$(PRJ_DIRS:%=/%.zip)))'

build: $(ZIP_FILES)

# Next line crashes because we can't use $@ in the prereq
$(ZIP_FILES): $(addprefix $(dir $@), $(SRC_FILE))
        touch $@
```

So one way to put the question:
**How can I write a rule the uses each corresponding `foo.py` file as a prereq to build the appropriate .zip file?**

Or, a more direct question that might actually be looking at this from the wrong angle:
**How can I refer to the specific target that's being built in the prereqs?**

Comment: Have a look at secondary expansion. IIRC, it lets you refer to the target variable in the prerequisites.

Comment: @eriktous: Yeah, I'd read a bit about that too but it seemed like a kludge - my guess is that there is a better (and probably obvious) way to go about doing this. But I'll give it another look. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, since you consider secondary expansion a kludge, it's `$(foreach ...)` and `$(eval ...)` to the rescue again (a very powerful combination).

Replace your rule with the following and you should get what you want.

```
define rule
$(SRCDIR)$(1)/$(1).zip: $(SRCDIR)$(1)/$(SRC_FILE)
    touch $$@
endef

$(foreach dir, $(PRJ_DIRS), $(eval $(call rule,$(dir))))
```